# DBMS or Software for privacy sensitive data

Tags: databases, privacy

We have a dataset of very privacy sensitive people data and want to build a database with it. The data protection department in our company doesn't like the idea that the data scientists are able to see any data specific to a person (even if anonymized). We can't preaggregate the data in the database because there are hundreds of different possible aggregations that could be interesting.

Is there a software or DBMS that could ensure that users can only query aggregated results that contain at least groups of N people?

How else would you solve this problem technically?

Comment: "aggregated results that contain at least groups of N people" would not make the data anonymized at all..

Answer (score 0):

Two possible options:

1. Have the database administer set limits on SQL queries that only allow result tables with aggregated results with minimum of N people to be returned.
2. Apply [differential privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy) which a query result cannot be used to infer much about any single individual, and therefore provides privacy.